# Rationale for BLAKE2 message schedule?

Tags: algorithm-design, sha-256, permutation, blake2

BLAKE2 uses a message schedule I did not see before. It uses permutations of pieces of the message block.

The BLAKE2 book did not state the rationale for such a choice and how it contrasts with the message schedule of SHA2 for example.

If the BLAKE2 key schedule is sound why wasn't such an approach taken with SHA0/1/2?

Comment: SHA-0 and SHA-1 are almost identical, and SHA-2 is a modernized version with more intricate rounds. I'm not sure that the design rationale behind SHA-0 has survived and if a function such as used in Blake would be considered at all at the time. Interesting question, and I hope that somebody can answer the "why", but please note that "why" questions are often hardest to answer; it might be required to pick the brains of the org. designer - and SHA-0 was not created through a competition...

Answer (score 1):

The permutation used in BLAKE2 is identical to the one used in BLAKE itself, so we can look at [the BLAKE specification submitted as part of the SHA-3 competition](https://web.archive.org/web/20170220231448/http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/sha-3/Round1/documents/BLAKEUpdate.zip):

> The permutations $ σ_{0}, . . . , σ_{9} $ were chosen to match several security criteria: First we ensure that a same input difference doesn’t appear twice at the same place (to complicate “correction” of differences in the state). Second, for a random message all values $( m_{σ_{r}(2i)} ⊕ c_{σ_{r}(2i+1)}) $ and $ (m_{σ_{r}(2i+1)} ⊕ c_{σ_{r}(2i)} )$ should be distinct with high probability. For chosen messages, this guarantees that each message word will be XOR’d with different constants, and thus apply distinct transformations to the state through rounds. It also implies that no pair $ (m_{i}, m_{j}) $ is
> input twice in the same $ G_{i} $. Finally, the position of the inputs should be balanced: in a round, a given message word is input either in a column step or in a diagonal step, and appears either first or second in the computation of $ G_{i} $. We ensure that each message word appears as many times in a column step as in a diagonal step, and as many times first as second within a step.

In some ways, this provides a similar purpose to the word expansion of $ W_{16} . . . W_{63} $ in SHA-256 in that it makes it harder for one particular word to cancel out another and hence cause collisions.  However, the BLAKE and BLAKE2 approach typically performs better and is more in line with the way ChaCha (on which BLAKE and BLAKE2 are based) works.  In addition, the usage of plain message words in a permutation is an approach that's also used in MD4 and MD5 (which are insecure, but have been influential in hash function design).

This doesn't answer why the designers chose specifically to use this approach rather than the SHA-2 approach, but it should be noted that goal was to be different from SHA-1 and SHA-2 (hence, why Keccak won), so it might also have been that resembling SHA-1 and SHA-2 greatly would have been seen as a disadvantage.